# How to read django session variables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a session variable `url_org_name` which I can read in django template by `{{request.session.url_org_name}}`. I wish to know how can I read the same in AngularJS.
I tried `sessionStorage.getItem('url_org_name')` but this didn't work.

Comment: what type of error did you get in the console?

Comment: @Jarachanthan Ratnakumar : I don't get any error. I get null.

Comment: Make sure your session is set in the session Storage at web browser

Comment: this session variable has already been set as I can read it in django template.

Comment: Try this $window.sessionStorage.getItem("url_org_name"); then tell me